# Transitioning to Spring Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

We are currently using Spring 3.2.3 + JPA (Hibernate).  We use aspects for transaction support as opposed to annotations.  We write out own entity services (read: repositories) to abstract the persistence away from our application.

I've read a lot about Spring Data and feel it would make our code considerably cleaner and more robust.  I wonder though, are there any gotchas that I should consider before transitioning?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already on JPA the transition should be as easy as it can be: activate the repositories, point the infrastructure to your `EntityManagerFactoryBean` and off you go.

Transactions should just work fine as well. The annotation based usage within Spring Data is selectively activated for the repository beans only. They are configured to take part in existing transactions by default, so any custom larger scoped transaction setting should be in effect already.